# In Scheme, what is the difference between `nil` and `null`?

Tags: null, scheme, empty-list, the-little-schemer

In "The Little Schemer", `null` is used to refer to the empty list `()`. But I also see the empty list referred to as `nil` in Scheme's Error message, e.g. doing:

`(car ())`

causes:

`Error: Attempt to apply car on nil [car]` [1]

Which sounds like it's referring to `()` as `nil`.

---

[1] using replit.com's BiwaScheme Interpreter version 0.6.4

---

This question is similar to [What is the exact difference between null and null in common lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826145/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-null-and-nil-in-common-lisp). It is different because as the answers here point out there are differences between Common Lisp and Scheme in their treatment of `nil` and `null`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the exact difference between NULL and NIL in Common Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826145/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-null-and-nil-in-common-lisp)

Comment: Is Scheme a descendant of LISP?

Comment: Yes, Scheme is a Lisp.

Comment: Do both `null` and `nil` refer to the empty list though? I read a few answers from your link, but didn't find the answer to that.

Comment: causes where? what implementation?

Comment: AFAICT, TLS only mentions "the null list", which uses "null" in its most common sense, as an adjective.  (Which is also what the `null?` predicate does.) `nil`, on the other hand, is a noun.

Comment: @WillNess I’m using Scheme in replit.com which is

`BiwaScheme Interpreter version 0.6.4
Copyright (C) 2007-2014 Yutaka HARA and the BiwaScheme team`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that what you're seeing is an artifact of history in the error messages.

In traditional Lisps, `nil` was both the empty list and boolean false, and was rather special in various other ways (for instance, it was *also* a symbol, which is very weird).

So in particular `()` and `nil` are the same object in such a Lisp, and `(not nil)` is true, and `(not '())` is also true (and in fact `(not ())` is both legal and also true).  The predicate for the empty list object is `null` (perhaps should be `nullp` but history says it is what it is) and `(null nil)` is true as is `(null '())` and `(null ())`.

There are also questions about what `(car nil)` *aka* `(car '())` *aka* `(car ())` should do.  Traditionally the answer was this was fine and `(car nil)` is `nil`.  This gives you a very neat implementation of `nil` if you're clever.

Scheme now does away with all of this punning:

- there is a unique false object which is `#f` / `#false`, which is not the empty list;
- all other objects, are true, so `(not x)` is true only for `x` being `#f`;
- there is a unique empty list object, which is `()`, which is not `#f` and which is therefore true;
- the predicate for this object is `null?`, so `(null? '())` is true, but `(null? #f)` is false;
- `car` and `cdr` of `()` are errors;
- `nil` is just a symbol with no special status in the language at all.

I don't think that having a name for `()` is standard, but obviously it might be useful to give it one, and `null` is fine: Racket does that, for instance.

So in Scheme, `nil` is just gone, and the pun between empty lists and boolean false with it.

But very many people who implement Schemes know that `nil` is what people call the empty list.  So when they write error messages, they write `nil` when they mean `()`, because that's what everyone has called `()` for a very long time.

And that, I think, is what you are seeing here.

Comment: May be worth adding: in Common Lisp `nil` and `()` are self-evaluating symbols, so `(null nil)`, `(null 'nil)`, `(null ())`, and `(null '())` are all ok. In Scheme `()` is _not_ self-evaluating, and `(null? ())` is a syntax error; the empty list must be quoted in Scheme: `(null? '())`. WRT `null`  vs `nullp` in CL: I sometimes wish it was `nullp`, and often I accidentally type `nullp`, especially after writing a bunch of Scheme code before writing some Common Lisp ;)

Comment: @adabsurdum: I agree with that, but I wanted not to get too far into the gory details of it (I had an earlier draft which had a lot more stuff in it but I think it just got too far from the original question).

Comment: In addition `()` is not a valid expression in Scheme. Some implementations allows it, but the standard is clear that you need to quote it to get the empty list.  eg. `(null? ())` would not be a valid Scheme expression while `(null? '())` is. OPs expression `(car ())` has the same problem and thus might fail before `car` application.

Comment: @Sylwester: yes. I think I've always quoted `()` in the answer except where explicitly pointing out that it was allowed unquoted in traditional lisps).  In fact I now always quote `()` in CL as well, in fact, because, well, because it makes more sense to me.  Once I used not to, but once I had no taste...

Answer (score 1):

The difference between different Lisps is how they handle true, false and nil.

In Common Lisp, we have `t` for true, and `nil` for false, although everything except `nil` is in fact true. Where the list is empty, or a `find` found nothing, we have `nil` and we can test directly. The technical term is `nil punning`.

```
'() ; => NIL
(= 1 2) ; => NIL
(if '() "full" "empty") ; => "empty"

(find 5 '(1 2 3 4)) ; => NIL
(if (find 5 '(1 2 3 4)) "found" "not found" ; => "not found"
```

Clojure does it differently. There is one official true value `true`, and there are two false values, `false` and `nil` - all values other than `false` and `nil` are also true. The empty list is no longer `nil`, and you need to use a separate test for an empty list, with `empty?`. The value `nil` is more like `void` in C. Better or worse? - you decide.

```
'() ; => ()
(= 1 1) ; => true
(= 1 2) ; => false
(if '() "full" "empty") ; => "full"
(if (empty? '()) "empty" "full") ; => "empty"
(if nil "full" "empty") ; => "empty"
(if (println "Hello world") "full" "empty") ; => empty
```

Scheme is much closer to Clojure in intent. Here there is one false value, `#f`. The empty list is no longer `nil`, and you need to use a separate test for an empty list, with `null?`.

```
(= 1 1) ; => #t
(= 1 2) ; => #f
(null? '()) ; => #t
(null? 'nil) ; => #f
```

So, `null` is another name for the empty list, but `nil` or `'nil` is not.

```
null ; => ()
nil  ; =>  cannot reference an identifier before its definition
'nil ; => nil
```

How about `(car ())`? Your Scheme returns `nil` from evaluating `()`, and that is what `car` is complaining about. My Scheme, Dr Racket, refuses to play at all, saying that the expression is missing from the empty list.